# win32com and PAMIE web page open timeout

Tags: python, time, multithreading, pamie

currently im making some crawler script,
one of problem is 
sometimes if i open webpage with PAMIE,webpage can't open and hang forever.
are there any method to close PAMIE's IE  or win32com's IE ? 
such like if webpage didn't response or loading complete less than 10sec or so .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use, to initialize your PAMIE instance, `PAMIE(timeOut=100)` or whatever.  The units of measure for `timeOut` are "tenths of a second" (!); the default is 3000 (300 seconds, i.e., 5 minutes); with `300` as I suggested, you'd time out after 10 seconds as you request.

(You can pass the `timeOut=` parameter even when you're initializing with a URL, but in that case the timeout will only be active *after* the initial navigation).

Comment: hello, sorry for late reply ..
your method is working very well .thanks !
i was add follow timeout option, and working well.
iepa = PAMIE(timeOut=100)
iepa.Visible = 1 
if some eorror encounter,can i add some error handling code?
when encounter error i want to go "def main():" for example..
you can some advice such like code for me?
thanks in advance!

Comment: @paul, the error will raise an exception (don't know which off-hand, and the docs are scanty, but can't you just look in the source?) and you can handle it with try/except (which you can place in `main` if you wish -- the exception will propagate up the chain of callers until it meets a suitable except clause).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is somewhere to set the timeout on your request. I would suggest looking into the documentation on PAMIE.